# Is UITableView's indexPathsForSelectedRows sorted by order of selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to perform actions on selected cells starting from the top of the table, going down.

Does `UITableView` `indexPathsForSelectedRows` return its rows in order that the user has selected them, or if it is an unordered set? I didn't see this in the official documentation and need to know if I need to sort the returned array in some way before performing operations where the order is important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it's not documented to return a sorted array, you should not rely on it being sorted even if it happens to be sorted in the current implementation.  The order might change in future versions of iOS.

Since `NSIndexPath` implements `compare:`, sorting the array is trivial:

```
NSArray *sortedIndexPaths = [[tableView indexPathsforSelectedRows]
    sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: This will sort them by indexPath though, and I think the OP would want (or expect) them to be "sorted" by selection order. I say "sorted" in quotes, because, it's not actually sorted, the indexPaths are just added in the order you select them. I guess Apple could change this in  the future to an array sorted by indexPath, but that seems like a remote possibility to me.

Comment: @rdelmar Please read the first sentence of Alex Stone's post.

Comment: Was that there before? Must be going blind!

Comment: Yeah, the order of selection is nice, but I want top down, so sorting by index path is the proper way to do this

Comment: Typo: indexPathsForSelectedRows (capitalization), but +1 anyway. :-)